# Scrape News with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape news articles from a Website. I am only interested articles that contain a `<span class="news_headline">` with the text "Transfers". From this article I want to extract the text inside the spans from `<div class="news_text">`. The result should end up in a csv file and look something like this:

```
R.Wolf; wechselt für 167.000 von Computer zu; Hauke  
Weiner; wechselt für 167.000 von Computer zu; Hauke  
Gonther; wechselt für 770.000 von Computer zu; Hauke
```

or

```
3378; wechselt für 167.000 von Computer zu; 514102  
3605; wechselt für 167.000 von Computer zu; 514102  
1197; wechselt für 770.000 von Computer zu; 514102
```

I am very new to programing so I hope anyone can help.

```html
<div class="single_news_container">
    <div class="news_body_right single_news_content">
        <div class="cont_news_headlines">
          <span class="wrapper_news_headlines">
            <span class="news_headline">Transfers</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="news_text">
            <div>
                <p>
                    <span><a href="/2.bundesliga/players/R. Wolf-3378">R. Wolf</a> wechselt für 167.000 von Computer zu <a href="/users/514102">Hauke</a></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span><a href="/2.bundesliga/players/Weiner-3605">Weiner</a> wechselt für 167.000 von Computer zu <a href="/users/514102">Hauke</a></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span><a href="/2.bundesliga/players/Gonther-1197">Gonther</a> wechselt für 770.000 von Computer zu <a href="/users/514096">Christoph</a></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, check the nested structure of the html code. You will see that the data you want to scrape is not wrapped in the `div` you mention, rather they're both wrapped in `<div class="news_body_right single_news_content">`. So you should run a `find_all` on that `div` and then loop the results to check whether within these `div`'s the news headline contains 'Transfers'. Only then you can extract the data by, for example, populating an empty list, then loading it in `pandas` and saving it to `csv`:

As `find_all` returns a list

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html='''<div class="single_news_container">
<div class="news_body_right single_news_content">
    <div class="cont_news_headlines">
      <span class="wrapper_news_headlines">
        <span class="news_headline">Transfers</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="news_text">
        <div>
            <p>
                <span><a href="/2.bundesliga/players/R. Wolf-3378">R. Wolf</a> wechselt für 167.000 von Computer zu <a href="/users/514102">Hauke</a></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span><a href="/2.bundesliga/players/Weiner-3605">Weiner</a> wechselt für 167.000 von Computer zu <a href="/users/514102">Hauke</a></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span><a href="/2.bundesliga/players/Gonther-1197">Gonther</a> wechselt für 770.000 von Computer zu <a href="/users/514096">Christoph</a></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

data = []

for news in soup.find_all("div", class_="news_body_right single_news_content"):
  if 'Transfers' in news.find("span", class_="news_headline"):
    for i in news.find("div", class_="news_text").find_all('span'):
      subject = i.find_all('a')[0].get_text()
      amount = i.get_text().split('für ', 1)[1].split(' von')[0].replace('.','').replace(',','.')
      from_player = i.get_text().split('von ', 1)[1].split(' zu')[0]
      to_player = i.find_all('a')[1].get_text()
      data.append({'subject': subject, 'amount': amount, 'from_player': from_player, 'to_player': to_player})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Result:

|  | subject | amount | from_player | to_player |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | R. Wolf | 167000 | Computer | Hauke |
| 1 | Weiner | 167000 | Computer | Hauke |
| 2 | Gonther | 770000 | Computer | Christoph |

Comment: Well that was quick! Thanks a lot, it works like charm. I will study what you did there and hopefully lern from it. Thanks again!